# How to force a value inside a Capybara feature Rails spec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I have the following:

spec/features/client_logic.rb

```
it "says unavailable slots" do
  expect(page).to have_content("No more client slots available.")
end
```

Which fails because in earlier `let` there is a `Plan` created with `max_clients` with 100. Is there a way to force a specific return value for a model at any given time for this feature?

I thought the following would work:

```
it "says unavailable slots" do
  Plan.any_instance.stub(:client_slots).and_return(0)
  expect(page).to have_content("No more client slots available.")
end
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your stub is setup correctly but it looks like it is being setup after the page you are testing has been rendered.

I'm not sure how your tests are structured but you may be able to get around the problem by creating a new context/feature and redefining the `let` within it, something like:

```
describe '...' do
  let(:plan) { ... }
  before do
    visit '...'
  end

  context 'without any client slots' do
    let(:plan) { ... }

    it "says unavailable slots" do
      expect(page).to have_content("No more client slots available.")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Right on, this was it. Thanks.